# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3) using PIL

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, rgb

I have an image of pixel size (1761, 460) and I am trying to find RGB values with Python using PIL. The image has 56 distinct colors in it. I am running the following code but I get an error saying:
`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`

Does anybody know a better method of doing this finding RGB values of an image?

```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import colorsys
  from PIL import Image

  img_file=Image.open("orange 4.png")
  img = img_file.load()
  [xs, ys] = img_file.size
   for x in range(0, xs):
           for y in range(0, ys):
            [r, g, b] = img[x, y]
              r /= 255.0
              g /= 255.0
              b /= 255.0
```

Comment: Are you sure the image is an RGB-mode image? It could be indexed.

Comment: @kindall check if it is an RGB mode image?

Comment: @kindall An indexed image generally has only 1 channel, i.e. the indices. If the error says it got too many values to unpack and it was expecting 3, the most likely guess Is that there are 4 channels, i.e. RGBA.

Comment: whoops, yes, of course. I read too fast and thought there were not enough values, not too many. remedy is the same, though: convert to RGB first.

Comment: Even after converting into RGB format I am getting the same error. @kindall

Comment: Are you doing `img = img.convert("rgb")` or just `img.convert("rgb")`? If the latter, you're throwing away the converted image and still working with the one you loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Not all PNG files are born the same.

There are many ways of specifying pixel information in PNG, [this document](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter08.html) shows 8 basic types. Depending on which type your file is in, each pixel could have 1, 2, 3 or four values associated with each pixel.

I'm guessing the file you're trying to open is RGB with alpha channel. You could use send the pixel information to a list and iterate over it like:

```
pixel = img[x, y]
r, g, b = pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2]
```

You could try to identify what sort of PNG you're dealing with, or you could convert your image to RGB using:

```
img_file = img_file.convert('RGB')
```

Comment: I tried it after using this conversion but I am still getting the same error. @Nicholas Abril